# Matlab sending data to Excel

Tags: excel, matlab

I have some problem exporting data to Excel file.
for example

This is result and problem is, the blank at the right end.
there suppose to be 0.947227532 but some how it's empty.
I have vague guess that it's because it has serial same value in a row.
Please tell me what to do.

```
 0.690745994    18.05949033 1.192653957 0.396440197
-0.044258514    3.46265691  0.947227532 
 0.679917786    12.28067074 1.322402497 0.396440197
 0.639375225    16.35981089               
 0.254060838
 0.637346185    16.30103417 1.034478957 0.241511727
 0.317693262    0.947227532 1.000000167 2.23117E-06
 0.669425212    14.80575942 1.007101536 0.094840169
 0.635785401    15.01130502 1.021861337 0.194297042
 0.640530449    16.36085872 1.039032143 0.254278537

rhoV3;
xlswrite('MING.xls', rhoV3, 'MING', 'M17')

rhoV4;
xlswrite('MING.xls', rhoV4, 'MING', 'Q17')

PV;
xlswrite('MING.xls', PV, 'MING', 'AA17')

WP2;
xlswrite('MING.xls', WP2, 'MING', 'S17')

Cd2;
xlswrite('MING.xls', Cd2, 'MING', 'T17')
```

these

Comment: Unfortunately your question cannot be answered in its current form. It's not clear what the values of the variables `rhoV3`, `rhoV4` etc. are. Are the numbers at the top of your question the inputs or outputs of the process?

Comment: that code is incomplete. Please write the example so that we can try it.

Comment: Maybe the code is complete and he's getting nothing in the excel file because he's passing in variables with nothing in them.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code so you can see the values of the arrays you are writing on the screen:

```
rhoV3
xlswrite('MING.xls', rhoV3, 'MING', 'M17')

rhoV4
xlswrite('MING.xls', rhoV4, 'MING', 'Q17')

PV
xlswrite('MING.xls', PV, 'MING', 'AA17')

WP2
xlswrite('MING.xls', WP2, 'MING', 'S17')

Cd2
xlswrite('MING.xls', Cd2, 'MING', 'T17')
```

I'd bet dollars to donunts that xlswrite is working fine and the problem is that `rhoV4` has fewer elements in it than you thought it did.  So fix `rhoV4` and you are done.

If I am wrong, come back with the results of that test, modify your question, and we can all try to figure it out.